# Running executable bash script with slash or without

Tags: bash

I have bash script `test.sh` which does nothing special:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello!
```

If I run it like this `. test.sh`, it works.

```
kopparberg:dev marek$ . test.sh
Hello!
```

If I run it like this `./test.sh`, it does not.

```
kopparberg:dev marek$ ./test.sh 
-bash: ./test.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between sourcing (`. test.sh`) the script and running it (`test.sh` or `./test.sh`) is in the first line.

If you source the script the first line is only a comment and ignored. But if you run it, the first line is examined by the kernel for the first two characters, and if they are "`#!`", the rest of the line will be used as the path and the first argument for an interpreter. That is the kernel will look for an executable named `/bin/bash` and pass it the name of the script as first argument. Like this: `/bin/bash ./test.sh`.

This is what normally would happen and you are right, it should have the same effect for your script. But your script contains a problem: The first line ends with a DOS line ending (CR LF) instead of a unix line ending (LF). So the name of the interpreter, as the kernel sees it is `/bin/bash^M` which does not exist on your disk (^M stands for the spurious CR before the line ending). To make matters worse, the ^M character is usually invisible.

You can prove that this is the case with `cat -v test.sh` (which prints the substitution ^M for the invisible CR character).

Answer (score 4):

The fist solution is an alias for "source" command.

The *shebang* is considered like a #comment for source

When you call the script with `./script`, the shell will execute the script with the *shebang* `#!/bin/bash`

The error you gave seems to be a CRLF problem, you can run :

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

to remove Windows end-lines.